# HTTPX returns 403, but requests 200. Python

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping, httpx

I'm trying to parse one site. I'm sending a naked http request, just by setting a User-Agent.

It's surprising how a request using "requests" returns a 200 response. But the same query using httpx returns 403.
I have tried making the request with both the 1.1 version of the http protocol and the 2.0 version. It didn't give any result.

I know that this site uses some protection against bots.

But why does the primitive "requests" do the job, as opposed to httpx?

I noticed that httpx adds a 'Host' header in its default request, which 'requests' does not.
But I don't know how to get rid of it.

30 sec video:
https://i.imgur.com/tWOe0sZ.mp4

Comment: I have similar problem. I read the server.log, The raw headers exactly the same for both requests and httpx. different only the sequence. but request get 200 and httpx get 403. Seeking solution., for almost 1 year

Comment: Not sure if this will help the current question but I have struggled for hours to understand why a call made with `requests` worked fine while the same call made with `httpx` did not. Turns out, a redirect was involved in my request. Adding `follow_redirects=True` solved my issue.

Comment: @Sorix Thanks for the feedback, but it's not about the redirect here. Redirects return a 3XX status code.

Comment: Found the problem. Something wrong with certificate loading on HTTPX.

Comment: did you find a solution? i have the same problem, some request with httpx return UnicodeEncodeError while with aiohttp they work fine

Answer (score 2):

Something wrong with HTTPX certificate. try this:

```
import httpx, ssl, certifi
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.load_verify_locations(certifi.where()) 
client = httpx.Client(verify=context)  
client.get('https://example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following User-agent in your header:

```
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.3"
```

it's possible that the server may be blocking requests from unfamiliar user agents. You can try setting the User-Agent header for your httpx request to a common browser or use the one from the requests package.